"error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout" but the remote branch was merged
I am working on a local branch where the remote version of the branch has been merged after a pull request was approved. The remote version of the branch was subsequently deleted after merging. So the branch only exists locally for me.
However, I can't get out of the branch now because when I try to git checkout main I get the error error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: with a list of files that I don't care about.
All variants of the solution
git add *
git stash
git pull

have failed on git pull with the error message
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/mybranchname'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

because the remote version no longer exists. I don't want to do git clean because there are some untracked files that I care about in my local directory. Help! How do I get unstuck?

The error message is pretty clear: you are not tracking those files but the operation you are trying to attempt to do will bring those files now as tracked files.... so, git is warning you about what you are trying to do. Why are those files being tracked now and they weren't before? Take a look at their history on the remote branch to find out. You could move your local files out of the working tree (or rename them so that they do not clash with the files that are now part of the branch) and then you could put your copies on top of the files in git once you have merged/pulled.

Oh.... and then there is the pullerror. Ok... the local branch mybranchname (my guess.... might be another name) has some-remote/mybranchname as the upstream..... but that branch has been removed, as you said. Git can't just guess what branch to pull from now.... so, you could instruct it what the new upstream branch is if you intend to keep on working on the local branch. For that you could use git branch --set-upstream-to=some-remote/some-branch.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=following+untracked+working+tree+files+would+be+overwritten.

To ignore the "overwritten" error, you can simply use git checkout -f main if you really don't care about the listed files. They will be overwritten by their versions in main without errors or warnings.
Another option, not recommended at all, is to write the patterns of these files to gitignore(like .gitginore or .git/info/exclude) first and then run git checkout main.
git pull is expanded to git pull origin $currentbranch but $currentbranch has already been removed from the remote repository. If the branch has been merged into main by the PR, you can use git pull origin main or git pull origin -r master(recommended, in case you have any new commit in the local branch) instead.
